# Redirecting from edge ie11 compatibility mode site

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, ie8-compatibility-mode

We have a react app which is added in enterprise edge ie11 mode, this is opening perfectly in ie11 mode but from this app when we do a redirection to an external authentication provider, that portal is opening in edge mode. We need that authentication provider page to be loaded in the ie 11 mode. I tried redirection using window.location.href=, window.location.assigen(),
window.location.replace() in all these cases the external app is opening in edge mode rather than ie11 compatibility mode.
Please help me in fix this

Comment: How did you configure IE mode? Is it through site list? Then you should manually add the external authentication provider portal page into the site list.

Comment: Through enterprise configuration, we added our application to the enterprise ie 11 sites, when we redirect to the authentication page it is opening in regular edge mode, i can see that the authentication page url is not configured in enterprise mode list

Comment: I've posted a solution in my answer. Please check it out.

Comment: Thanks, will try to apply that and see.

Answer (score 0):

In order for IE mode to work properly, authentication/ ADFS / Single Sign-On servers will need to be explicitly configured as neutral sites. Otherwise, IE mode pages will try to redirect to Microsoft Edge and authentication will fail.

A **neutral site** will use the browser where the navigation started - either Microsoft Edge or IE mode. Configuring neutral sites ensures that all applications using these authentication servers, both modern and legacy, continue to work.

You can configure neutral sites by setting the Open In drop down to 'None' in the Enterprise Mode Site List Manager tool or by directly updating the site list XML:

```
<site url="login.contoso.com">
       <open-in>None</open-in>
</site>
```

To identify authentication servers, inspect the network traffic from an application using the IE11 Developer Tools. If you need more time to identify your authentication servers, you can configure a policy to keep all in-page navigation in IE mode. To minimize the use of IE mode, disable this setting once you've identified and added your authentication servers to the site list. For more information, see [Configure in-page navigation to remain in IE mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#internetexplorerintegrationsiteredirect).